# Legal Move Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java

So I am attempting to code a tic tac toe game in java. Most of it is done, however, I cannot give back an invalid move if someone chooses a space that is already taken.

Here is the code I'm trying to figure out. I thought that since the space is represented by the number 0 (My professor told us this), having

```
board[i][j] == 0
```

in the if statement would stop the player from repeating that space.

```
public static boolean isLegalMove(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 0 && row <= 2 && row >= 0 && col <= 2 && col >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, it seems like your loop is unnecessary and overcomplicating your logic.  You already have the row and the column you want to check, so there's no reason not to use those:

```
public static boolean isLegalMove(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    return board[row][col] == 0;
}
```

This has the risk of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but that's more of a symptom of the ancillary methods `getRow` and `getCol`, and you should ensure that those can't return an out-of-bounds value.  You should ask for what you want to simplify things instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `for` loops, just checking if `board [row][col]` is `0` is enough.

```
public static boolean isLegalMove(int[][] board, int row, int col) {
    return ( ( row <= 2 && row >= 0 && col <= 2 && col >= 0 ) && board [ row ] [ col ] == 0 );
}
```